# How to mock a null response using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq for mocking a method call and I want to mock a null response. The `Login` method returns a `LoginResult` type.

My Login interface:

```
public async Task<LoginResult> Login(string userPin)
```

My unit test mock:

```
var credentialsService = new Mock<ICredentialsService>();
credentialsService.Setup(x => x.Login("1234")).ReturnsAsync((LoginResult)null);
```

With the above mock, I receive the following warnings:

warning 1:

> Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

warning 2:

> Argument of type 'ISetup<ICredentialsService, Task>' cannot be used for parameter 'mock' of type 'IReturns<ICredentialsService, Task<LoginResult?>>' in 'IReturnsResult ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<ICredentialsService, LoginResult?>(IReturns<ICredentialsService, Task<LoginResult?>> mock, LoginResult? value)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types.

How can I resolve these two warnings?

Comment: what version of dotnet are you using? can you add the .csproj and the definition of LoginResult please?

Comment: Does putting a `!` after the `null` work? `credentialsService.Setup(x => x.Login("1234")).ReturnsAsync((LoginResult)null!);`

Comment: Your example uses `LoginResult` but the warning shows the actual type of the members being mocked to be `LoginResult?`. That is the cause of the type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact if you don't setup your mock then it will return `null` by default?

This is due to the fact that the `Mock<T>()` constructor uses the `MockBehavior.Default` value.

The `MockBehavior` can have the following values:

- `Strict`: an exception is thrown whenever a method or property is invoked without a matching configuration
- `Loose`: Moq accepts all invocations and attempts to create a valid return value
- `Default`: same as `Loose`

So, if you would define your mock with `MockBehavior.Strict` then you would receive an exception if there were no `Setup`-`Returns` statements. But because the default behaviour is `Loose` that's why you do not need to perform any `Setup`-`Returns` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The shown example uses `LoginResult` but the warning shows the actual type of the expected return type to be `LoginResult?`. That is the cause of the conversion warning.

```
credentialsService.Setup(x => x.Login("1234")).ReturnsAsync((LoginResult?)null);
```

If using `ReturnsAsync` is causing issues, use `Returns` with the `Task` created manually

```
credentialsService
    .Setup(x => x.Login(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(s => Task.FromResult<LoginResult?>((LoginResult?)null));
```